# Reactjs change value when its clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable `id` that has already had value, I just want that if the user click the ClearIcon the id will turn to null. so that he does not become equal to `location.id`

```
  const [getId, setId] = useState(id)
  
  const stopSearching = () => {
    setId(null)
  };
  <IconButton onClick={stopSearching} edge="end">
    <ClearIcon />
  </IconButton>
  {console.log(getId)}
  {filteredLocations.map((location, index) => (
     <LocationWidgetItem
        key={index}
        location={location}
        onClickLocation={setActiveLocation}
          selectedLocation={location.id ==getId}
     />
  ))}
```

Comment: You need update id in state, then it will appear properly.

Comment: `onClick` is being handled by `stopSearch` but the handler/function you defined is `stopSearching`, is it just a typo in question? if not make sure that both have the same name. Also set `id` to `null` in the `stopSearch` function.

Comment: @K450 yes it is a typo, sorry

Comment: is it still not working after setting `id` to `null` in the `stopSearching`?

Comment: my problem is in `location.id ==getId` the getId is undefined

Comment: const [getId, setId] = useState(id)
here is the issue i think, the id inside useState(id) must be the initial value of the id state. Do this instead: const [getId, setId] = useState(null)

Comment: @NickGr and? how about the if condition in my jsx?

Comment: it can remain the same as it was (``location.id ==getId``) It was probably getting undefined because in your useState as I meantioned above you set the initial value to ``id`` which is probaly a variable that you haven't decalred

Comment: I dont know where the `id` in `useState(id)` is coming from but it is the initial value of a state variable, so if `id` is not defined in the code then thats the issue. As @NickGr said just set it to `null` initially if you dont have any initial value to set it to.

Comment: you need to understand that in `const[getId, setId] = useState(id)`, `getId` and `setId` are not getter and setter function for state variable `id`. But here the state variable is `getId` and to set its value you call `setId()` and the `id` is the initial value of the state variable.

Comment: To avoid confusion i'd suggest to use `const [id, setId] = useState(initalValue)` just as @HimanshuSingh provided in answer. Here `initialValue` can be any value you want to store in the state variable `id` on initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `id` a state variable?

**Note**: `id === null` is for equality comparison.

If is a state variable like

```
const [id, setId] = useState(initialValue);
```

then do it like this:

```
const stopSearching = () => {
    setId(null)
  };
```

---

If it is not a state variable, then to trigger rerender, it need to be a `prop` and there must be some function to change `id prop`.

---

Since I can't understand the query exactly, it will be better to add your code in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io).

For now, I am adding a method,

```
const [getId, setId] = useState(0);
//I am taking id 0 as initial value, you can pick any other value
  
  const setActiveLocation = (id) => {
    setId(id);
  }
  const stopSearching = () => {
    setId(null)
  };
  <IconButton onClick={stopSearching} edge="end">
    <ClearIcon />
  </IconButton>
  {console.log(getId)}
  {filteredLocations.map((location, index) => (
     <LocationWidgetItem
        key={index}
        location={location}
        onClickLocation={() => setActiveLocation(location.id)}
          selectedLocation={location.id === getId}
     />)}
```

Comment: the id is state variable, ive tried this solutions but it doesnt work, the console id is undefined in jsx

Comment: the id i mean is in const [id, setId]

Comment: `selectedLocation={location.id ==id}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set it with setId

```js
const stopSearching = () => {
    setId(null)
};
```

so that will automatically invalidate the previous content and will set the

```js
    selectedLocation={location.id ==getId}
```

to false

Comment: `const[getId, setId] = useState(id)` just like this?